utt_int variable type in T-SQL
I am updating a old report that was built by a contractor builder a few years ago, and I ran into a "primary key" variable defined as 'utt_int'  I have never hear of it before, and I can't find anything about it online.
This is the statement:
DECLARE @vst_int_id_tbl utt_int 
INSERT Into @vst_int_id_tbl select(6963215)

Does anyone know anything about it and how to use it?

Could have been a user-defined table type. I mean, it almost certainly is. You can look the types up when you connect to the database with SSMS.

@TT: I looked it up and you might be right, however, it still doesn't mention anything about how to handle/use this type.. but that fall more on my lack of experience that any thing else.

It's quite a normal Table Type. You can see it in SSMS under Programmability -> Types -> User-Defined Table Types. It works like a normal table variable, except that you can also pass it between procedures or from client code as a parameter. At a guess, judging from the name and columns, it's probably declare as CREATE TYPE utt_int AS TABLE (someColumnName int); See also https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/use-table-valued-parameters-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver16 and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-type-transact-sql

@Charlieface has fully answered the question with their comment.
The indicated datatype is a user-defined table type that appears to consist of a single column of type INT
A common utilization pattern for this sort of object is to pass multiple integers at a time as a parameter to some other code object
In practice, an object of this type is handled similarly to a table variable
